# stream.AddLocation doesn't work by itself

Tags: twitter, tweets, tweetinvi

My code failed with the last TweetInvi API. To make it work, I have to combine it with an AddTrack.

The following code works only if I uncomment "stream.AddTrack()".

```
var stream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
stream.AddLocation(new Coordinates(-180, 90), new Coordinates(180, -90));
//stream.AddTrack("xbox");

stream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) =>
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned on github, the problem is that you are not using the `Coordinates` class properly.

You simply inverted you coordinates latitude and longitude.

```
stream.AddLocation(new Coordinates(90, -180), new Coordinates(-90, 180));
```

Comment: Thanks.  That solved the problem.  The code used to work with older version of TweetInvi.